# Cannot create breaks in highcharts legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to put together a highcharts legend that has different sections, headers and breaks. Unfortunately it looks like the highcharts legend formatter only allows you to wrap individual items, and not insert line breaks or indeed any meaningful HTML. In other words, it is not possible to move around the little 'color boxes'. The only way you can move them is by inserting spaces in the text, etc.

The below link shows you a (very very nasty) hack that unsuccessfully attempts to implement what I am trying to do. Have you any better way to achieve a legend that can be properly broken up into different parts, etc?

http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/6c3meof9/1/

Really nasty hack:

```
legend: {
    labelFormatter: function () {           
        if (this.x == 0) return '<span class="subhead">Group 1</span>' + this.name;
        else if (this.x == 1) return this.name + '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp' ;
        else if (this.x == 2) return '<b><span class="subhead">Group 2&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span></b>' + this.name;
        else if (this.x == 5) return this.name + '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp' ;
        else if (this.x == 6) return '<b><span class="subhead">Group 3&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span></b>' + this.name;
        else return this.name;
    },
    useHTML: true
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main problem is that the color coded legend is rendered in SVG, while the text is render in HTML using absolute positioning. It would be quite hard to achieve what you want. Can you check the documentation for Highcharts and see if you can customize the legend a bit more? That or use another chart rendering plugin / script.

Comment: It needs to be said here, that once your chart gets this complex for what should be something fairly straightforward...perhaps you're going about displaying your data the wrong way. A pie chart is minimally useful in the best of cases, utterly useless with so many data points and such a complex legend structure.  FWIW

Comment: I am just trying to insert a line break in the legend and a subheader... The pie chart is just an example. :)

Comment: Line breaks aren't going to help because the legend is constructed with absolutely positioned elements. You might stand a better chance by plotting each group as a separate series.

Comment: Roamer, that sounds like an interesting idea and a potential way forward, could you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: It's just a possibility that separate series (a) can be made to plot on the same pie chart (b) will yield separate legends that can be more easily labelled "Group 1" etc.

Comment: Not exactly what you want but here's something based on one of the Highcharts demos - http://jsfiddle.net/dabvok6r/.

Comment: The best solution is disable legend and create your own in html. Simple examples: http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/ / http://jsfiddle.net/cCF9T/

Comment: Sebastian, that is the answer I am looking for. A quick question on performance: is this likely to slow down chart loading time if there are many series?